balcony edge DIY on a rounded balcony?
I've got a balcony that has been poorly made, causing water to get behind the plaster and that plaster falling off.
Question
Is this something I can DIY? How (just pointers to sources would be really helpful) ?
Additional Details:
I'm the owner so I can do what I want. I'm not the original builder. It's a detached house.
The main issues I see is that a) the balcony is already finished, so anything that needs embedding or putting under the concrete is difficult and b) the balcony is rounded, not straight.
My goal is to have an edge that closes off the plaster front so that water either drains to the sides or runs off the front but can't get behind the plaster. Ideally it can be installed from the top - I can take out the glass panels and get to the edge from above much easier than from below.
Here is a picture taken from below showing the edge and a place where plaster broke off already. The thin things on top are the floor tiles of the balcony.

